# How to stay updated as an Android Developer?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm an Android Developer with more than 7 years in the software industry. Right now I'm at a point where my knowledge is outdated and I'm looking for a way to get updated with all the recent changes and trends.

Comment: You can refer to https://kotlinlang.org/ for updating yourself in Android, and for Android API Levels we have got old and gold https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platforms

Comment: go to android developers channel on youtube and watch the videos from the Developers' summit and I/Os of the last coupel of years. All new features and technologies are being presented there. Going forward you could follow the codelabs that they suggest to make sure you stay current and informed aout all the latest changes and best practices.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: Voting to close this (good) question because it is the wrong place to ask this kind of general questions. iCantC answer will help you hopefully : https://stackoverflow.com/a/60261475/1327557 and I find Slack groups useful too ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several options:

1. Answer other people's questions on stack overflow. Most of the time they are questions you will never ask yourself.
2. Try out the new android apis, and look for quirks... Android compatibility issues are a ... (no good word for it)
3. Look through google play at apps you did not develop, and try to figure out how they work (code wise)
4. Try writing automated tests for apps you did not write, to see how that works.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @NikosHidalgo comment, all I want to add is,

**Just surround yourself with Android**.
 Not just in working hours but even out of it.

> 1. Subscribe to Android NewsLetters(*Android Weekly*).
> 2. Subscribe to Medium Android Community.
> 3. Subscribe to Android youtube channels( *So that, as soon as you open Youtube you see Android feeds*).
> 4. Follow Android Development pages on **Instagram**, **Facebook**, so that you are aware of what's new in Android, even in your free time.
> 5. Follow some of the top Android Developers/Consultants/Advocates on **Twitter**.
> 6. When you are doing non-coding tasks(*Walking, Cleaning*) hear out Android Podcasts.
> 7. Attend Android Meetups, great for building a network and learning
>      new stuff.
> 8. Join the Android group on **Reddit**.

***Just make your whole environment include Android in it.***